# HStoreField() query in Django for finding and Count values in HstoreField

Tags: python, django, hstore, django-hstore

I'm working on HStoreField in  Django. I can able to store the data in HstoreField().
but i dont know how to retrive data from hstore filed

**models.py**

```
class myhstore(models.Model):
file_name= models.CharField(max_length = 20)
content = HStoreField()
```

I am storing data as

file_name = "Sample.csv"

```
content

{'Name':'A','Age':'21','Place':'AAA'}

{'Name':'B','Age':'20','Place':'BBB'}

{'Name':'C','Age':'21','Place':'CCC'}

{'Name':'D','Age':'20','Place':'AAA'}

{'Name':'E','Age':'21','Place':'CCC'}

{'Name':'F','Age':'22','Place':'AAA'}
```

and in Postgre table it is storing as

```
"Name"=>"A", "Age"=>"21", "Place"=>"AAA"
"Name"=>"B", "Age"=>"20", "Place"=>"BBB"
"Name"=>"C", "Age"=>"21", "Place"=>"CCC"
"Name"=>"D", "Age"=>"20", "Place"=>"AAA"
"Name"=>"E", "Age"=>"21", "Place"=>"CCC"
"Name"=>"F", "Age"=>"22", "Place"=>"AAA"
```

Here , i need to query from table using python 
as

if selecting "Place" need Values in Place and their count like

AAA - count- 3 
BBB - count- 1
CCC - count- 2

if selecting "Place" and "Age"

AAA,21 - count - 1

AAA,20 - count - 1

AAA,22 - count - 1

BBB,20 - count - 1

CCC,21 - count - 2

Please help me to do this..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?